# using instruments to check for memory leaks in xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, instruments

How to use instruments to check for memory leaks in xcode 4? In the documentation they mention how to use it in earlier version of xcode which is done simply through the toolbar run with performance tool then selecting leaks. any idea how use the instruments in xcode 4.0. if you have any good tips or site that help me using it as I am first time user of the instruments.
thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer to this Question.To use the instruments in Xcode4 go to product then profile then select the instrument that u want.